# Should I provide a setter for a list object in Java?

Tags: java, oop, object, constructor

I've got a class with a list object like this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MyClass
{
    private List<String> myList;

    //???
}
```

Now, to let other classes access the list, I'll have to add one of the following:

- a getter and a setter
- *or* a getter and a setter and initialize the list in the constructor with an empty ArrayList
- *or* a getter and a setter and initialize the list in the constructor with a list passed on the constructor arguments
- *or* a getter and a setter with both constructors
- *or* only a getter and initialize the list in the constructor with an empty ArrayList
- *or* only a getter and initialize the list in the constructor with a list passed on the constructor arguments
- *or* only a getter with both constructors

What is the best thing to do? Are there conventions?

**EDIT**: By "letting other classes access the list" I mean nothing specific, just general usage, letting other classes work with the list, store and read objects in it.

Comment: The best thing to do depends on the need and your need "to let other classes access the list" is not clear. Please be more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a single way or convention to allow a List field from a class to be "provided" to another class.

> By "letting other classes access the list" I mean nothing specific,
>   just general usage, letting other classes work with the list, store
>   and read objects in it.

You have broadly two ways to provide information about a List field from a class to another class :

- in a protected way. The two classes are not designed to be very coupled and besides you want to protect data that are added in the List from the class that contains the List.
  So, you don't provide getter and setter for the List but instead you may provide public methods to read and add data in the List.
  In this way the client class stays not coupled from the implementation of the used class : it doesn't know that a List is used and the single responsible of the List (adding/getting/moving, ... operations and rules applied for them) is its owner.
  An alternative way for accessing the List is providing a getter for the list but by providing it as unmodifiable :

  `public List<YourClass> getReadonlyList(){
     return Collections.unmodifiableList(originalList);
  }`
- in a coupling way. The two classes are designed to be very coupled. So, providing a getter and a setter for the List is not necessary a problem. It may be even very suitable as it avoids introducing useless complexity.

Answer (score 1):

Data hiding and encapsulation is always a good principle

this is kind of hard to decide without an specific architecture, many tools can live with many will die without that...

you can be gentle to the developers using our class and allow them to use setters and giving those unmodifiable collections of your list.

it will depend on how much the soft developer will need to deal with the list after an instance of MyClass is created.

Comment: Maybe too fast..your answer looks like a detailed comment but good anyway :)